# Regex to find the first image in an image tag in an HTML document

Tags: regex, web-scraping

What is a regex to find the first image in an image tag in an HTML document? My previous tries have not really worked, as they just matched based on `.jpg"` and didn't put into account edge cases such as having an image with a cachebuster timestamp at the end (`asdf.jpg?581291823`)

Edit: I'm using Node.js. I'd like to do HTML parsing, but we have a lot of documents to parse, so I'm not sure if HTML parsing is the best option as it takes considerably more time.

Comment: Use a DOM Parser instead of unreliable HTML parsing with regex. Which language are you using? Provide a sample input and output as well to get better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As anubhava correctly points out, regex is not 100% reliable for parsing HTML. However, for one-shot-tasks, (i.e. not production code), a regex solution can do a pretty good job (and is quite fast as well):

Capture the image URL filename (sans query or fragment) from the first IMG element into group `$1`:

`<img\b[^>]+?src\s*=\s*['"]?([^\s'"?#>]+)`

Note that there are certainly edge cases where this does not work.

**Edit:** Added `">"` to the negated SRC attribute value character class.

Comment: Might want to deal with unquoted URLs as well, if you can figure out a good way to handle them. Your pattern will handle `<img src=someUrl />` just fine, but `<img src=someUrl/>` or `<img src=someUrl>` will break it. I can't think of a simple way to deal with this without breaking something else. Anyway, +1 for mentioning parsers and for a decent solution where no pattern will be perfect.

Comment: Update: Having thought about it, `<img\b[^>]+?src\s*=\s*['"]?([^\s'"?#>]+)(?<!/)` should at least deal with that one problem.

Comment: @Justin Morgan: Good points. I've added the `>` to the char class to handle one of the cases you mention. Since the OP did not specify a language, I left out using any look behind (so this would work with Javascript). I think the `<img src=someUrl/>` case is highly unlikely because the empty-element-closing-slash will only be found in XHTML which will typically have quoted attribute values. Thanks for the heads up (and your attention to detail).

Answer (score 3):

This is a perfect example of a task that is **tricky and unreliable** with regex, and **almost trivially easy** with an HTML parser. Use a parser for this, not regex.

You haven't said which language you're using, but I've heard some very good things about [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/), and the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), which use Python, PHP, and .NET, respectively. Trust me--[save yourself some pain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) and use those instead.

Edit: If you **must** use a regex, go with @ridgerunner's pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Scraping html, a simple and very loose regex would be: `/\<img.*?src="(.*?)"/`

Using a real DOM parser is of course the preferred method.