# Strip specific HTML tags using Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'd like to hear if anyone can help to to replace my large XML file's HTML markup.

The XML file has my own schema and it's all fine. But I need to remove `<sspan>, <style>, <div>` and attributes in `<p>` tags.

For an example, I need to keep all `<ul>, <ol>, <li>, <strong>, <a>, <img>` and other tags but remove `<div>` (with attributes), `<span>` (with attributes), and attributes in `<p>` tags.

I have tried many examples from this site and many other sites. But most of them didn't worked.

Comment: First of all, [don't use regex to parse XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). That being said, can you list some of the things you've tried that haven't worked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from [an answer I posted yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613178/regex-to-find-the-first-image-in-an-image-tag-in-an-html-document/6613762#6613762):

> I've heard some very good things about
>   [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), [HTML
>   Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/), and the [HTML Agility
>   Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), which use Python, PHP, and
>   .NET, respectively. Trust me--[save
>   yourself some pain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) and use those
>   instead.

I **strongly** advise you not to use regex for this. No sane regex is going to work, or probably even come close to working. However, a decent XML parser can do this fairly easily. I'm not sure what programming languages you have access to, but if you can use PHP, .NET or another programming language, you can use the above parsers to find each `span`, `style`, `div`, and `p` and remove attributes or the entire tags.

jQuery has some good functionality for DOM-manipulation like you're describing, and you can use it to generate HTML which you then cut and paste.

If you absolutely **must** use regex, you could try this:

- Pattern: `<\s*/?\s*(span|style|div)\b[^>]*?>`
- Replacement: (nothing)
- Pattern: `<\s*p\b[^>]*?>`
- Replacement: `<p>`

Comment: Hi justin, I never thought I will get such perfect answer from the world. Thank you!     Actually I tried 3 codes you mentioned and as I know some php, I tried php method. Worked perfectly!    Also, regex - I now agree that RegEx is not a good solution to kill such HTML tags but for this case.  RegEx patterns worked greatly! Thank you again.